# Where does Breslov teach about Rosh Hashanah?

Tags: torah-study, rosh-hashanah-new-year, breslov

I'm looking to learn what R. Nachman of Breslov taught about Rosh Hashanah? Is there anything in Likutei Moharan? If so can you direct me to the Siman? I'm not exclusively looking for anything about Uman. Just his teachings on the Yom Tov in general.

Comment: Maybe hilchos rosh hashana

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel That would be in Likutei Halachos, from his student, R. Nosson.

Comment: @oliver Isn't lilukuti morahan from the student, r. Nossann?

Comment: @Mordechai Written by R. Nachman’a student(s) - yes, but they were ideas the former conveyed to them. However LH is the pupil’s original writing [based on his master’s teachings].

Comment: thanks all but could anyone provide more specific source references?  I'm not just asking about his teaching's on Uman but about the holiday more broadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you have found what you were looking for, but in case you can for example look at Torot 1, 5 and 8 in Likoutey Moharan Part 2 (Tinyana)